# How to know when a Composable like TextField gains focus?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I want to trigger a function upon my `TextField`'s focus-gain, but I am unable to find something like a listener.

Comment: I don't think using ```Modifier.focusable()``` on a ```TextField``` would be an appropriate choice, since it is already focusable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `onFocusChanged` modifier

```
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it},
    modifier = Modifier.onFocusChanged {
        if (it.isFocused){
            //...
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Hmm that oughta do it

Answer (score 2):

One can collect the latest focus state from the TextField's interaction source:

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val isFocused by interactionSource.collectIsFocusedAsState()
```

Use this `interactionSource` as the argument for your TextField `interactionSource` parameter.

```
TextField(
    // ...
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
)
```